# How to delete a consul service

Tags: consul

I've created a bunch of test services in my consul cluster I wish to remove, I have tried using the /v1/agent/service/deregister/{service id} - and ensured it runs fine on each node - I can see this run on each node

[INFO] agent: Deregistered service 'ci'

Is there another way to manually clean out these old services ?

Thanks,

Answer (score 10):

Try this

```
$ curl \
--request PUT \
https://consul.rocks/v1/agent/service/deregister/my-service-id
```

Comment: replace consul.rocks with appropriate consul host, port name in the url

Answer (score 5):

Login in to the consul machine,and issue the command as follow:

```
consul services deregister -id={Your Service Id}
```

Answer (score 4):

1. fetch service info `curl $CONSUL_AGETNT_ADDR:8500/v1/catalog/service/$SERVICE_NAME | python -mjson.tool` :

   `{
       "Address": "10.0.1.2",
       "CreateIndex": 30242768,
       "Datacenter": "",
       "ID": "",
       "ModifyIndex": 30550079,
       "Node": "log-0",
       "NodeMeta": null,
       "ServiceAddress": "",
       "ServiceEnableTagOverride": false,
       "ServiceID": "log",
       "ServiceName": "log",
       "ServicePort": 9200,
       "ServiceTags": [
           "log"
       ],
       "TaggedAddresses": null
   },
   ...`
2. prepare a json file, fulfill the values with the above outputs `cat > data.json` :

   `{
     "Datacenter": "",
     "Node": "log-0",
     "ServiceID": "log-0"
   }`
3. deregister with: `curl -X PUT -d @data.json $CONSUL_AGETNT_ADDR:8500/v1/catalog/deregister`

Comment: This will not work.  The service will be deregistered, but will "come back" in a few seconds when the node syncs.  Instead, do:

`curl -X PUT http://localhost:8500/v1/agent/service/deregister/SERVICE-ID`

Answer (score 0):

You can clear service config in config directory mannually

Comment: in the days of dockerisation is there a better approach?